# PX4/Firmware make error

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, makefile, px4

Question： When I run `make px4fmu-v2_default`， I get this：

```
rootroot:~/Firmware$ make px4fmu-v2_default

Makefile:44: Not a valid CMake version or CMake not installed.
Makefile:45: On Ubuntu, install or upgrade via:
Makefile:46: 
Makefile:47: 3rd party PPA:
Makefile:48: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x -y
Makefile:49: sudo apt-get update
Makefile:50: sudo apt-get install cmake
Makefile:51: 
Makefile:52: Official website:
Makefile:53: wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.3/cmake-3.3.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
Makefile:54: chmod +x cmake-3.3.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
Makefile:55: sudo mkdir /opt/cmake-3.3.2
Makefile:56: sudo ./cmake-3.3.2-Linux-x86_64.sh --prefix=/opt/cmake-3.3.2 --exclude-subdir
Makefile:57: export PATH=/opt/cmake-3.3.2/bin:$PATH
Makefile:58: 
Makefile:59: *** Fatal。 停止。
```

My CMAKE version

```
root@root：~/Firmware$ cmake --version

cmake version 3.0.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

Why？

Comment: It is an internal check of [firmware makefile](https://github.com/PX4/Firmware/blob/master/Makefile). It wants all things with the correct repos installed, as the error suggest.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/PX4/Firmware/blob/master/Tools/check_cmake.sh:

```
if [[ $cmake_ver == *" 2.8"* ]] || [[ $cmake_ver == *" 2.9"* ]] || [[ $cmake_ver == *" 3.0"* ]] || [[ $cmake_ver == *" 3.1"* ]]
then
  exit 1;
fi
```

The code explicitly rejects cmake versions 2.8, 2.9, 3.0 (including your 3.0.2), 3.1.

You need to upgrade your cmake to at least version 3.2.